# How to return to command line in 12.04 server

Tags: command-line, server

How do I return to the command line in Ubuntu 12.04 server when all there is, is a line with nothing but a flashing underscore on it. I typed a command wrong and it is stuck like this.

Comment: What command did you type wrong?

Comment: I tried putting a 4 at the end of the ping command like this, ping 8.8.8.8 4, because when I tried ,ping 8.8.8.8, it just kept saying unable to connect to host and kept retrying over and over again and I didn't know how to stop the ping sequence so I just restarted the pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to press **CTRL+Z**, you should get a prompt then type `bg` to resume it but running as a background process.

You can type `ps -aef` to look for the command PID to eventually kill it:

```
sudo kill -9 PID_of_your_command
```

Comment: How can i scroll up through those PIDs. There are too many to fit on one screen. Also which column is the PID?

Comment: if you can't scroll try a simple `pkill ping`

Comment: Is there any way to make it so I can scroll up through the results?

Comment: Maybe `ps -aef | less`

Comment: Ctrl-C is the way to kill a command, or `kill PID`. `kill -9` should be used only as a last resort, because it will not leave the process do the cleanup.